# Filtering using a boolean array in numpy now raises a deprication warning. How to avoid this and why was this change made?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

While using numpy today I was writing a couple lines to pull elements from a 1D array with several different identifying integers in a sequence.  My filter is fiveseventy_idx but I got a deprication warning.  How would I do this in the future

```
    fiveseventy_idx = np.where(clusters == 1)
    clusters = clusters[fiveseventy_idx]

<ipython-input-44-fd1ca1277d36>:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  fiveseventy_idx = np.where(clusters == [1,570])
```

Say hypothetically `clusters = np.array([2, 4, 2, 7, 7, 7, 1, 1, 3, 570, 1,])`, and I only want specific integers, my filter is required for another array so I can get associated values in the same order as before. So I would want `[1,1,1]` after applying my filter.

Comment: I don't follow.  How can you compare a 12 item array with a 2 element get 3 ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing 2 arrays of different length - the result is scalar `False`, along with the warning:

```
In [146]: np.arange(10) == np.array([2, 5])
<ipython-input-146-888c04a597c2>:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  np.arange(10) == np.array([2, 5])
Out[146]: False
```

So it's just saying - no the 2 arrays are not equal.  Normally though `numpy` will be doing elementwise comparisons.  And it may, at one time just truncated the longer array to match the size of the shorter.

Anyways, a `broadcasted` comparision:

```
In [147]: np.arange(10)[:, None] == np.array([2, 5])
Out[147]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False]])
In [148]: (np.arange(10)[:, None] == np.array([2, 5])).any(axis=1)
Out[148]: 
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False])
In [149]: np.nonzero((np.arange(10)[:, None] == np.array([2, 5])).any(axis=1))
Out[149]: (array([2, 5]),)
```

Sometimes `all` can be used to test for catching `True` in both columns.

Another way:

```
In [151]: np.isin(np.arange(10),np.array([2,5]))
Out[151]: 
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False])
```

or

```
In [152]: (np.arange(10)==2)|(np.arange(10)==5)
Out[152]: 
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False])
```